# Save Realm object to DB

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to save a Realm object to database and have one problem. When I run project i'm getting an error:

> "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
>     Referenced from: /Users/levchukmisha/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6C527B07-299E-4B4F-B093-C2E79011AD3E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1DA8CC9D-FDEC-4A75-8B6D-19C3AF3508EF/BookShop.app/BookShop
>     Reason: image not found"

I tried to comment my property image and check what happens, but error still the same.

Here is my function:

```
func addBook() {
    let newBook = Book.createBook(
        name: "11 22 63",
        author: "Steven King",
        cost: 150,
        about: "Very interesting book with fantasty elements",
        image: UIImage(named: "112263")!)


    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(newBook)
            print("\(newBook.name)")
        }
    } catch {
        error.localizedDescription.description
    }


}
```

And here is my realm object:

```
class Book: Object {

@objc dynamic var name = ""
@objc dynamic var author = ""
@objc dynamic var cost = 0
@objc dynamic var about = ""
@objc dynamic var image = UIImage()

class func createBook(name: String, author: String, cost: Int, about: String, image: UIImage) -> Book {
    let newBook = Book()
    newBook.name = name
    newBook.author = author
    newBook.cost = cost
    newBook.about = about
    newBook.image = image

    return newBook
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you dragged Realm.framework to the "Embedded Binaries" section in your project's General settings tab. Also make sure you have "Embed Frameworks" build phase and Realm.framework is included there

[Installation section in documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation) select a tab according whether you're using CocoaPods or Carthage

Take note of this :

If using Realm with Swift, drag the file at Swift/RLMSupport.swift into the File Navigator of your Xcode project, checking the Copy items if needed checkbox.